# Google Apps Script: Clone PDFs to new folder

Tags: google-apps-script

Afternoon all,
I am trying desperately to get a script to work and from what I can see it should work perfectly. I want to get a list of PDFs from the source folder and make copies of said PDFs into a secondary folder.
Here is the script:

```
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("source");
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("target")
  var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(targetFolder);  
  }
```

Am I missing something? Do I need permissions to use google scripts on drive? I am very confused.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you passing an `id` here or a `name`: `DriveApp.getFolderById("source")` ?Because you need to pass the id of the folders, not their name. Also, do you see any error? and if yes, what it is?

Comment: I can confirm, you are **not** passing the id of the folders but their names. Your code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As per Marios mentioned in the comment, your code does work. Just make sure to copy the proper ID of the folder.

Your code should look like the code below when including the folder IDs

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B55C21aJsSBlfk9FTjRqOG8tb3hjR1N4MTU1YjVPNU4weGVhSldfU3F4OXladVVNMF9Ccms");
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1n9PJ_FFlJvlCRdWxHHJiTn4RF6-a1ypE");
  var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(targetFolder);
  }
}
```

[image: sample output]

Please see [this](https://learn.azuqua.com/connector-reference/googledrive/#:%7E:text=Navigate%20to%20the%20folder%20in,ID%20would%20be%20%E2%80%9C1dyUEebJaFnWa3Z4n0BFMVAXQ7mfUH11g%E2%80%9D.) to see how you get the folder ID.

Note that when you see a `?key=value` format, don't include that and anything after that. They are called [URL parameters](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6277564?hl=en) and is not a part of the Folder ID